# Change icon size with XML when working for different display sizes?

Tags: android, xml

I want to be able to change icon size on demand when designing layout for different display sizes. One option i can think of is having the same icon multiple times in the folder in different sizes, and use accordingly, but i wonder if there is a way to have the same icon but sized dynamically in every different xml iteration.

Comment: you can use image asset which sizes the icon based on layout size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to deal icon wrongly because your are going to resize the icon multiple time according to the screen density , which will make your icon pixelized .

You have to follow the best approach to deal with icon .

[Here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) you can generate all type of assets for android , just copy the icon generated to your res folder and let the system choose the right icon size for you.