# android - vector asset icon multiple display size support

Tags: android

As stated in [this](http://www.androiddocs.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) official android document, we need to create diffent icon for different display size, for example:

```
res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png         // bitmap for medium-density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png         // bitmap for high-density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for extra-high-density
res/drawable-xxhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra-extra-high-density
```

It's really tedious so I wish to create one version xml icon (vector asset by android studio), since xml is vector image, it should be good to scale to different screen size.

How can we use the same version xml icon to support different screen size? should I copy it to different directory just like different dimension png files? Or just keep one copy in drawable directory then everything will works fine?

Comment: please check my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434578/change-icon-size-with-xml-when-working-for-different-display-sizes/56434726#56434726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put one copy of the vector XML file in `res/drawable` and the system will take care of the rest for you.

Comment: Thanks, current I create the 24x24 xml and define the ui with android:layout_width="40.0dip" android:layout_height="40.0dip", so that means it will be 40dipx40dip. should I remove these statements? I still confused why a vector icon still has 24x24 concept!

Comment: The dimensions given in the `<vector>` tag define the image's _intrinsic dimensions_. In your case (24x24), if you use `wrap_content` it will be 24dp by 24dp. Also, if you're using compile-time PNG generation (which generally you should not), these dimensions will define the baseline size (so the mdpi PNG will be 24x24, the xhdpi will be 48x48, etc).